# Is it mandatory to install Google Service APK to use Maps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to known if it's posible to show Google Maps v2 without forcing user to install Goolge Services APK, because my app its for private use in a company, and the future users don't have permission to access google play and the don't have a goolge account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every Android device comes with Google Play services pre-installed and it is not possible to run Map without google play sevices.Thats why you can't test Map in Emulator.

Comment: yes maps require google play services

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan. I have a problem now :P